# Clairaut Theorem Counterexample

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Do you know one function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{xy}(a,b)=f_{yx}(a,b)$ at point $(a,b)$ but $f_{xy}$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$?

Comment: Wikipedia had an example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives under the tab “Requirement of Continuity”

Comment: @User8128 I don't think that is the example that the OP is looking for. Wikipedia gives an example of an $f$ where the second derivatives are not symmetric because of the failure of continuity. The OP is looking for an $f$ with symmetric second derivatives even though the second derivatives are not continuous.

Comment: Clairut Theorem states, in the 2-dimensional case, "$f_{xy}$ and $f _{yx}$ continous at (a,b) implies $f_{xy}(a,b)=f_{yx}(a,b)$". I'm looking for an example to prove that converse statement is false.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function:

$f\left( x,y \right)=\left\{ \begin{align}
  & \frac{{{x}^{2}}{{y}^{2}}}{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}},\quad \left( x,y \right)\ne \left( 0,0 \right) \\ 
 & 0\quad \quad \quad ,\quad \left( x,y \right)\ne \left( 0,0 \right) \\ 
\end{align} \right.$

It can be shown that  ${{f}_{xy}}\left( 0,0 \right)={{f}_{yx}}\left( 0,0 \right)$ but $\underset{\left( x,y \right)\to \left( 0,0 \right)}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{f}_{yx}}\left( x,y \right)\ne 0={{f}_{yx}}\left( 0,0 \right)$