# When does the Clairaut's theorem fail?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

What type of functions fail to pass the Clairaut's theorem, are there trigonometric type of functions that meet this criteria?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734866/clairaut-theorem-counterexample

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example that I know of is
$$
  f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{x y (x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
  0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
 \end{cases}
$$
Using the limit definitions, you can show that $f$ is twice-differentiable, but $f_{yx}(0,0) = 1$ and $f_{xy}(0,0) = -1$.